# Accessing DB Column data within a for loop (It doesn't work when I have $i in the end of the name)

Tags: php, database, wordpress, for-loop

I think my problem might be fairly simple, but I can't get it to work.

I have a custom DB Table with similar column names. The difference between columns is the number in the end, so we have name11, name12, name13. At the same time though, we have name21, name22, name23 and so on.

I am using a for loop inside of a for loop in order to retrieve the data of that specific column. 
The following code, however, does not work.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo('<table>');
  for($j=0; $j<10; $j++)
  {
    echo('<tr>');
      $field_name = $user_routines[$i]->exercise_name.($i+1).($j+1);
      echo('<td>' . $field_name . '</td>');
    echo('</tr>');
  } 
}
```

Besides that, I have also tried the following:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo('<table>');
  for($j=0; $j<10; $j++)
  {
    echo('<tr>');
      echo('<td>' . $user_routines[$i]->(exercise_name . ($i+1) . ($j+1)) . '</td>');
    echo('</tr>');
  } 
}
```

But it didn't work either.

**Ps1:** `$user_routines` is an array that contains my table rows for a specific user.

Thanks! =]

Comment: don't you have ids in the db? **name#** .. sounds like your db is set up wrong

Comment: Yes I do. There's nothing wrong with the db or the table. In fact, if I simply use `$user_routines[$i]->exercise_name11` it works fine, but since I have many fields similar to that, it would be much better to use a for loop to populate the page fields.

Comment: name# looks *wrong* to me, but its your life

Comment: It would be helpful to know more specifically what you mean by "does not work." What actually happens? And in general, you will need to use [complex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to refer to object properties this way.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, by "it doesn't work" I mean that it does not return anything. To be more specific, my syntax is probably wrong. If I write `echo ($user_routines[$i]->exercise_name11);` it **DOES** return the value that I want, but like I stated above, I have many of those, so I am trying to get the same result with something similar to this: `echo ($user_routines[$i]->{'exercise_name'.($i+1).($j+1)});` However, when I reload the page, there's nothing there.

Comment: Just to be sure, the ones with single digits, are they `exercise_name01` rather than `exercise_name1`? Also, not returning anything sounds like you probably don't have error reporting turned on. Turning it on would certainly make it easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, there's no single digit. it goes from `exercise_name11` to`exercise_name79` 

Alright, I turned it on and this is what I get:
For this line: `$field_name = $user_routines[$i]->exercise_name.($i+4).($j+1);` I get the following: _Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$exercise_name_ 

Now, for the line: `echo ('<td>' . $user_routines[$i]->{$field_name} . '</td>');` I get the following: _Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$11_ 

And lastly, but not least, for the line: `echo ('<td>' . $user_routines[$i]->{'exercise_name'.($i+1).($j+1)} . '</td>');` I get *nothing*

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  $tmp1 = ($i+1);
  $tmp2 = ($j+1);

  $id = "$tmp1"."$tmp2";
  echo '<td>' . $user_routines[$i]->{'exercise_name'.$id} . '</td>';
```

Assuming inside your array $user_routines[$i] is an object inside.
**Please paste a small piece of your array structure**.

Comment: Here's part of it: 

array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#506 (295) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["routine_name"]=> string(9) "DB Test 1" ["routine_type"]=> string(7) "bulking" ["routine_split"]=> string(1) "1" ["nameday1"]=> string(17) "Chest and Triceps" ["nameday2"]=> string(0) "" ["nameday3"]=> string(0) "" ["nameday4"]=> string(0) "" ["nameday5"]=> string(0) "" ["nameday6"]=> string(0) "" ["nameday7"]=> string(0) "" ["exercise_name11"]=> string(0) "" ["exercise_sets11"]=> string(1) "0" ["exercise_reps11"]=> string(1) "0" ["exercise_rest11"]=> string(1) "0" ["exercise_name12"]

Comment: That's what I get with "var_dump"